# How to get the output from a specific layer from a PyTorch model?

Tags: python, pytorch

How to extract the features from a specific layer from a pre-trained PyTorch model (such as ResNet or VGG), without doing a forward pass again?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

## New answer

**Edit:** [there's a new feature in torchvision v0.11.0 that allows extracting features](https://github.com/pytorch/vision/releases/tag/v0.11.0).

For example, if you wanna extract features from the layer `layer4.2.relu_2`, you can do like:

```py
import torch
from torchvision.models import resnet50
from torchvision.models.feature_extraction import create_feature_extractor

x = torch.rand(1, 3, 224, 224)

model = resnet50()

return_nodes = {
    "layer4.2.relu_2": "layer4"
}
model2 = create_feature_extractor(model, return_nodes=return_nodes)
intermediate_outputs = model2(x)
```

## Old answer

You can register a [forward hook](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/nn.html#torch.nn.Module.register_forward_hook) on the specific layer you want. Something like:

```py
def some_specific_layer_hook(module, input_, output):
    pass  # the value is in 'output'

model.some_specific_layer.register_forward_hook(some_specific_layer_hook)
    
model(some_input)
```

For example, to obtain the `res5c` output in ResNet, you may want to use a `nonlocal` variable (or `global` in Python 2):

```py
res5c_output = None

def res5c_hook(module, input_, output):
    nonlocal res5c_output
    res5c_output = output

resnet.layer4.register_forward_hook(res5c_hook)

resnet(some_input)
    
# Then, use `res5c_output`.
```

Comment: How does the value of output get returned here?? hook functions are not allowed to have a return value, so I don't see how fc1000_output in your code will get the value of output assigned to it. How does the value res5c_output get passed to fc1000_output?

Comment: I added a missing `nonlocal` declaration. It's not that the value of `res5c_output` gets passed to `fc1000_output`, it's that the former variable is bound to the outer context.

Answer (score 3):

The accepted answer is very helpful! I'm posting a complete example here (using a registered hook as described by @bryant1410) for the lazy ones looking for a working solution:

```
import torch 
import torchvision.models as models
from torchvision import transforms
from PIL import Image

def get_feat_vector(path_img, model):
    '''
    Input: 
        path_img: string, /path/to/image
        model: a pretrained torch model
    Output:
        my_output: torch.tensor, output of avgpool layer
    '''
    input_image = Image.open(path_img)
    
    preprocess = transforms.Compose([
        transforms.Resize(256),
        transforms.CenterCrop(224),
        transforms.ToTensor(),
        transforms.Normalize(mean=[0.485, 0.456, 0.406], std=[0.229, 0.224, 0.225]),
    ])
    
    input_tensor = preprocess(input_image)
    input_batch = input_tensor.unsqueeze(0)

    with torch.no_grad():
        my_output = None
        
        def my_hook(module_, input_, output_):
            nonlocal my_output
            my_output = output_

        a_hook = model.avgpool.register_forward_hook(my_hook)        
        model(input_batch)
        a_hook.remove()
        return my_output
```

There you have your features extraction function, simply call it using the snippet below to obtain features from `resnet18.avgpool` layer

```
model = models.resnet18(pretrained=True)
model.eval()
path_ = '/path/to/image'
my_feature = get_feat_vector(path_, model)
```

Answer (score 0):

Alternative for using `register_forward_hook`, but with a class rather than a global variables.

Simple example:

```
class FeatureExtractor:
    def __init__(self):
        self.extracted_features = None

    def __call__(self, module, input_, output):
        self.extracted_features = output

extractor = FeatureExtractor()
model.some_specific_layer.register_forward_hook(extractor)
model(some_input)
extractor.extracted_features
```

Extracting from multiple layers (storing in a dictionary):

```
class FeatureExtractor:
    def __init__(self):
        self.extracted_features = dict()

    def extract_features(self, module, input_, output, name):
        self.extracted_features[name] = output

    def get_forward_hook(self, name):
        return functools.partial(self.extract_features, name=name)

model.some_specific_layer.register_forward_hook(extractor.get_forward_hook(layer_name))
model(some_input)
extractor.extracted_features[layer_name]
```

[`functools.partial`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functools.html#functools.partial) allows us to create a *callable* that maps to `FeatureExtractor.extract_features` with a specific argument already passed to the *name* argument.